# How to upload local image using Python Requests to Cloudsight?

Tags: python, python-requests, cloudsight

I am currently trying to send a POST request to an image recognition API called CloudSight using Python Requests. I have gotten it working with an image URL, but am struggling to get it to send a local image file. My code so far is:

```
import requests

LOCALE = 'en-US'
LANGUAGE = 'en-US'
URL = 'http://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_responses/'

header = { 
        'Authorization' : 'CloudSight meSNWQPE7LZ_ybXLMlDflA'
    }

imageFile = {'file': ('cigarette.jpg', open('cigarette.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg')}

def postRequest():
    print("Here we go again...")
    print(imageFile)

    postData = {
        'image_request[image]': imageFile,
        #'image_request[remote_image_url]': 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
        'image_request[locale]': LOCALE,
        'image_request[language]': LANGUAGE
    }

    rPost = requests.post("https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests", headers=header, data=postData)
    print(rPost.status_code)
    print(rPost.text)
```

I am aware that generally Requests sends files using the parameter "files" in the POST request itself:

```
rPost = requests.post("https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests", headers=header, data=postData, files=imageFile)
```

However, I have tried both ways and each time get the error: `{"error":{"image":["at least one of image or remote_image_url must be set"]}`

I also know that the variable is definitely getting the image correctly, as if I print the contents of the variable it gives: `{'file': ('cigarette.jpg', <_io.BufferedReader name='cigarette.jpg'>, 'image/jpg')`} As I understand it, the API requires it to be sent in the parameter "image_request[image]" (according to their docs: https://cloudsight.readme.io) How do I send the image file to CloudSight correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try calling the file with the expected name?

```
imageFile = {'image_request[image]': ('cigarette.jpg', open('cigarette.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg')}
rPost = requests.post("https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests", headers=header, data=postData, files=imageFile)
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately I just get the same error... any other ideas? :/

Comment: Wait, no, I made a stupid mistake; that works beautifully! Final code looks like this: http://hastebin.com/axoyonayiz.py